# Why my backgroundworker do not work for progress bar

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, progress-bar, backgroundworker

Why my background worker does not work for progress bar (By default set visibility to false .).

I am trying to have a progress bar in the background. when the user clicks OK button then I start the timer and make the progress bar visible.
and run   backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(); and in backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted i set visibility of progress bar to false.

The problem is it just shows the progressbar but do not show the progress.

My code is here :

```
        private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer.Start();
            progressBar.Visible = true;
            backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
           doSomeWork();
        }

 private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            timer.Stop();
            progressBar.Visible = false;   
        }

        private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("called");
            if (progressBar.Value == progressBar.Maximum)
            {
                progressBar.Value = progressBar.Minimum;
                return;
            }
            progressBar.PerformStep();
        }

        private void backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }
```

Why does it not show progress in the progress bar ? Does whats wrong in it ?

Comment: `Problem is it just shows the progress but do not show the progress.` What do you mean?

Comment: please see the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `backgroundWorker_DoWork` is not doing anything. Move `doSomeWork` in `DoWork` event. And you need to set `ReportProgress` to `true`.

```
private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer.Start();
    progressBar.Visible = true;
    backgroundWorker.ReportsProgress = true;
    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    doSomeWork();
}

private void doSomeWork()
{
  //do what you want here..
  backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(yourprogresspercentagenumber);
  //do what you want again..
  backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(yourprogresspercentagenumber);
}
```

Comment: thee where progress bar value change ?

Comment: @testtest see my update. You could set the report progress value in `doSomeWork` function.

Comment: You are right, i have already tried it was showing progress in progrss bar but the problem using this way of achieving is, My form is suppose to be hide itself(this.hide()) and popup another form in doSomething() function but the progress bar finsihes 100 % even i do " backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(100, null);" after form2.showdialog(); but that form2 never popups

Comment: @testtest that is a different question. Please post a new one for that.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing two concepts here. Please decide if you want to use a timer *or* a background worker.

The reason why nothing happens is that your `backgroundWorker_DoWork` does *nothing*. So the background worker is immediatly finished and `backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted` is called, stopping your timer again.

`backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged` is never called, because that event is only raised if you call [`backgroundWorker.ReportProgress()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t(v=vs.110).aspx) (and have `backgroundWorker.ReportsProgress` set to `true`).

I think the work you do in `doSomeWork()` should be done in `backgroundWorker_DoWork` while reporting progress. Try somthing like this:

```
private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    progressBar.Visible = true;
    backgroundWorker.ReportsProgress = true;
    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    doALittleWork();
    backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(10, null);
    doMoreWork();
    backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(20, null);
    //...
    doLastWork();
    backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(100, null);
}

private void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar.Visible = false;   
}

private void backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

This should do what you want. The timer is not needed in that scenario.

Comment: Thanks rene ...how would you go for it if you have to achieve the same ? Please explain through comments . Thank you so much.

Comment: You are right, i have already tried it was showing progress in progrss bar but the problem using this way of achieving is, My form is suppose to be hide  itself(this.hide()) and popup another form in doSomething() function but the progress bar finsihes 100 % even i do "  backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(100, null);" after form2.showdialog();  but that form2 never popups.

Comment: @testtest that seems to be a different question, so maybe post a new question for that.